# Panorama Page Layout Change? Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to know when the panorama view gets changed from say a current title "Settings" to "Help"? I need this so I know what view to open if they click the add button or remove appbar buttons.

So lets say we got a panerama view like:

[image]

How can we know when the user changed from the recent part to the part the phone is currently on or the network part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Panorama` control raises a `SelectionChanged` event each time the user navigates from one `PanoramaItem` to the next. You can then determine the index of the current page by inspecting the `SelectedIndex` property.

Answer (score 1):

**PanoramaControl** has a property called **SelectedIndex**, which gives the index of the currently selected **PanoramaItem**. By this index you can decide which page has been selected.